# external jar file include in java binding library in monodroid?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2010, jar, xamarin.android

i am just starting to develop in monodroid , i know android and c# too. i have created android app using viewflow example. so i have now viewflow library 's jar file , i have included that .jar file in my monodroid java binding library as defined in http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Advanced_Topics/Java_Integration_Overview/Binding_a_Java_Library_(.jar). But when i build that java library project i have got following error.. i have stuck with this almost 3 hrs.
'Org.Taptwo.Android.Widget.ViewFlow' does not implement inherited abstract member 'Android.Widget.AdapterView.RawAdapter.set'

Answer (score 2):

This has been filed as [bug 11279](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=11279). The workaround is to add a file to your binding project with the following contents:

```
using Android.Runtime;

namespace Org.Taptwo.Android.Widget {

  partial class ViewFlow {
    protected override Java.Lang.Object RawAdapter {
      get {return Adapter.JavaCast<Java.Lang.Object>();}
      set {Adapter = value.JavaCast<global::Android.Widget.IListAdapter>();}
    }
  }
}
```

Change the namespace and type name as appropriate to fix other binding projects.

Comment: hi Jonathan,can you please see this questions :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801057/java-binding-library-native-thumbnailator-lib-xamarin-android .
thanks!

Comment: @jonp Could you check similar topic issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026284/xamarin-android-library-binding-remove-override-modifier