# Java Binding Library native Thumbnailator Lib Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, java-binding, android-native-library

i'm trying to add into my project this [lib](https://github.com/coobird/thumbnailator).
So i've added **Java Binding Library** to my **Xamarin.Android** project and after compile,i've got some problems.

Tried to resolve by my self and didn't get a luck.
So i removed packages,via **remove-node** that i wont to use and all complies fine,but i have strange behaviour.

Class,that i want to use is empty(that how is he showed on assembly browser):

```
using Android.Runtime;
using Java.Lang;
using System;

namespace Net.Coobird.Thumbnailator.Util.Exif
{
    [Register("net/coobird/thumbnailator/util/exif/ExifUtils", DoNotGenerateAcw = true)]
    public sealed class ExifUtils : Object
    {
        //
        // Constructors
        //
        internal ExifUtils(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer);
    }
}
```

And the original(source .java version) is looks like [this](https://github.com/coobird/thumbnailator/blob/master/src/main/java/net/coobird/thumbnailator/util/exif/ExifUtils.java).
Why this happens? It unusable.
Thanks!

Comment: Check the [diagnostic build output](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output), which will hopefully state why it's skipping the `getOrientationFromExif()` method. As a guess, it's because the `Orientation` type couldn't be found.

Comment: @jonp thanks for the reply.ill try to use diagnostnic build output. So as i understand that,need to implement "enumerator",because there is difference between Java enum and C#?

Comment: There shouldn't be a need to implement "enumerator"... I'm don't understand.