# Xamarin Android library binding, remove override modifier

Tags: dll, xamarin, binding, xamarin.android

I am trying to bind an Android PDF library in a Xamarin Android Binding project, but a unnecessary "override" modifier is added to a property:

```
public partial class ReaderView : global::Android.Widget.AdapterView, [...] {
    // ...

    public override unsafe global::Android.Widget.IAdapter Adapter {
        // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.artifex.mupdfdemo']/class[@name='ReaderView']/method[@name='getAdapter' and count(parameter)=0]"
        [Register ("getAdapter", "()Landroid/widget/Adapter;", "GetGetAdapterHandler")]
        get {
            // ...
        }
        // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.artifex.mupdfdemo']/class[@name='ReaderView']/method[@name='setAdapter' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='android.widget.Adapter']]"
        [Register ("setAdapter", "(Landroid/widget/Adapter;)V", "GetSetAdapter_Landroid_widget_Adapter_Handler")]
        set {
            // ...
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

I didn't find anything about adding/removing modifiers like "override", or "virtual" in [the documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata/).

I tried this without success:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.artifex.mupdfdemo']/class[@name='ReaderView']/method[@name='getAdapter' and count(parameter)=0]" name="override">false</attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.artifex.mupdfdemo']/class[@name='ReaderView']/method[@name='setAdapter' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='android.widget.Adapter']]" name="override">false</attr>
```

Do you guys have any idea about how to do this?

**Edit 1**: The Java project is on GitHub: https://github.com/asimmon/MuPDF-for-Android and here is a [direct link to the file ReaderView.java](https://github.com/asimmon/MuPDF-for-Android/blob/master/src/com/artifex/mupdfdemo/ReaderView.java).

**Edit 2**: The Xamarin Binding Project is on GitHub too, you will find the Jar library: https://github.com/asimmon/MuPDF-for-Xamarin-Android

Comment: Why would you remove this modifier? Does the `.jar/.aar` specifically have an `@override` for this item? Can you upload the .jar/.aar to your question? I would think so given it's the implementation of an `Adapter` of `AdapterView`: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Widget.AdapterView.RawAdapter/ and in native Java - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getAdapter() / https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setAdapter(T)

Comment: @JonDouglas, I've added links to the GitHub repos. I will try to see if the `@override` is necessary tomorrow, thank you.

Comment: What was the solution? We have the same issue when binding library that  inherits from Android.Widget.AdapterView and have overridden get and set Adapter methods.

Comment: @JonDouglas main issue here is Xamarin non generic version of Android.Widget.AdapterView does not have Adapter property or getAdapter / setAdapter methods but is exposing RawAdapter property (https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.AdapterView/). To get access to Adapter property it should be using generic version (https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.AdapterView%3CT%3E/).

Comment: Proposed workaround https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=11279

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to modify the `visibility` of the method in `Metadata.xml`:

```
<attr 
   path="/api/package[@name='com.artifex.mupdfdemo']/class[@name='ReaderView']/method[@name='getAdapter']"
   name="visibility">public</attr>
```

This effectively removes the `override` keyword from your method's signature.

Comment: Worked for me, might not be relevant though in newer Xamarin versions.

Comment: What?? Why? How? What if the method is already `public`? This did not work for me btw.